# Continuous solutions of a certain functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let the following functional equation be given:

$$\frac{f(x+y)+f(2y)}{f((x+y)2y)}=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{f(xy)}+y.$$

where function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$. I'm looking for any continuous solution of this equation, but I have a hard time to do this. Maybe such a solution doesn't exist? On the other hand, very similar equation

$$\frac{f(x+y)+f(2y)}{f((x+y)2y)}=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{f(xy)}+2y$$

has infinitely many continuous solutions (i.e. $f(x)=\frac{a}{x}$, $a>0$).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Basically, I tried two things. First, based on the solution of the latter equation, I was looking for solution related to $\frac{a}{x}$, and, second, because equation contains expressions from well-known Cauchy equation, I tried to find some substitutions that can transform my equation to the form similar to Cauchy equation. Unfortunately, I didn't succedd in both attempts.

Comment: I also tried to compute some values of $f$ straight from equation (like $f(1)$) but with no success.